# is it possible the client computer boots the OS from server rather than having own OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, remote-access

Is it possible that when user starts computer then OS is loaded from the server and i can update install apps while on the server and it should appear on user computer.

User can have their own drive or storage but main OS will on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The name of what you're looking for is a thin-client. Usually it is network-booted via PXE. The main benefit is that you can run beefy processes on light hardware, since the server is doing the crunching.

If all you want is patch management, maybe you should check out WSUS.

Comment: Basically what i want to solve this problem. Every time some formats his computer . beside installing windows i have to install some common softwares like winrar , acrobat reader, vlc player , anitvirus

Is there any way that those gets automatically installed from some place with first log on or cleints can use them using server or any other option

Comment: Mirror51, it sounds like you need to start building images for your workstations instead of installing the OS and applications from the ground up each time.

Comment: Look into Norton Ghost or get to know the "dd" *nix command. ;-)

Comment: I think she is right , i need to look into building images of workstations and i case of problem reload that image

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  Desktop virtualization, and many companies offer solutions in this space.  Wikipedia has a good overview with links to the vendors:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization